# How to programmatically create indexing from the list of urls in java

Tags: solr, lucene, nutch

I want to create search engine. So I had used nutch and solr for the developing it.
But it is not able to crawl each and every url of the website and search results are not as 
good as Google.So I started using jcrawler to get list of url.
Now I have list of urls.But I have to index them.
So is there any way where I can index list of urls stored line by line in a file.
and show results vis lucene or solr or any other Java API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you programmatically do something really depends on which language you plan on writing your code in - fetching content from a URL and making sense of that content before indexing will be largely dependent on the libraries available for your programming language of choice.

You can still use nutch with the Solr backend - give it the list of urls as input and set `--depth` to `1` (so that it doesn't spider anything further).

There are also other "ready" options, such as [Crawl Anywhere](http://www.crawl-anywhere.com/) (which has a Solr backend) and [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

"Not as good as Google" is not a good description of what you want to accomplish and how to approach that (keep in mind that Search is a core product for Google and they have a very, very large set of custom technologies for handling search). If you have specific issues with your own data and how to display that (usually you can do more useful results as you have domain knowledge of the task you're trying to solve), ask concrete, specific questions.

Comment: I was just comparing my search results  which i got from nutch and solr which were not as fine as Google custom result api of the same website.So, I just want to have close enough, at least 80-90 %. Hence comparing with Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data Import Handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler) to load the list of URLs from file and then read and index them.

You'd need to use nested entity with outside entity having *rootEntity* flag set to false.

You'd need to practice a little bit with DIH. So, I recommend that you first learn how to import just the URLs into individual Solr documents and then enhance it with actually parsing of URL content.